# adding margin-left changing animation to parent's sibling's child tag(JQUERY)

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I need to add margin-left changing animation to parent's sibling's child tag when button is clicked and it isn't possible with CSS.

I tried JQuery animate method and doesn't work

CSS:

```
div.sideMenuBar{
        display:inline-block;
        width:80px;
        color:black;
    }
    div.sideMenuBar.hiddenBar{
        margin-left:-100px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <header>
    <div class="barButton">
          <div class="bar1"></div>
          <div class="bar2"></div>
          <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
    <h1 class="Rubrik" > Tillgångar </h1> 
</header>
<div class="body">
    <div class="sideMenuBar hiddenBar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" >SideBar1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SideBar2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SideBar3</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
 $('div.barButton').on('click',function(e){
            $(this).toggleClass('change');
            //$('div.sideMenuBar').slideToggle();
            $('div.sideMenuBar').toggleClass('hiddenBar');
            if($('div.sideMenuBar').hasClass('hiddenBar')){
                $('div.sideMenuBar').animate('margin-left',0);
            }else {
                $('div.sideMenuBar').animate('margin-left','-100px');
            }
        });
```

Problem is changing class is working, so margin changes but I need animation and animate() method doesn't work.